# Couldn't access to db with Zencart

Tags: mysql, database, passwords, zen-cart

Trying to copy a zencart website in another server, but after openning the right port and copying the database, i have this error while openning the url in an internet browser.

```
    0 DB_ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED
in:
[select * from project_version WHERE project_version_key = 'Zen-Cart Database' ]
If you were entering information, press the BACK button in your browser and re-check the information you had entered to be sure you left no blank fields.
```

Does'nt anyone already encounter this error ? Or have suggestion of how to solv this ?
Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone which encounter the same problem.
It comes from the fact that the password were saved in an old format on mysql.

You should migrate them to the new format to solv this issue:

```
update user set password=password('<my_password>') where user = '<my_user>';
flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something in `includes/configure.php` is wrong.  Check each of these values very carefully:

```
define('DB_PREFIX', ''); 
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');  
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', '');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', '');
```

You likely have a typo in one of them, or perhaps you forgot to specify the prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I will try that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please mark this answer as correct and upvote if this fixes your problem.